# Authenticate bot with azure Active Directory, to access sharepoint API

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have a list on my sharepoint site, and an API url to get the list from.

I created an azure directory app, based on the bot I created, giving it sharepoint permissions and delegations.

In my bot I'm using `adal-node` to get a token using clientId/clientSecret. The response back looks like

```
{ 
  tokenType: 'Bearer',
  expiresIn: 3599,
  expiresOn: Tue Sep 06 2016 17:26:19 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time),
  resource: 'spn:00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000',
  accessToken: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJS....d0fWNHCxdWjyRnrUBV-jks47XRzmeO...9IP-6DXknubwj6ui2v...e9LCgs_ZUZiMXmg',
  isMRRT: true,
  _clientId: '<clientID>',
  _authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<AppID>/oauth2/authorize/<tenantName>' 
}
```

I'm passing the token into the header like so

```
  var options = 
{ 
    method: 'GET',
    url: "https://uccentric-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mysite/test/_api/lists/GetByTitle('SharepointLearningPlan')/items",
    headers: 
    {
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        Authorization: token.tokenType + ' ' + token.accessToken,
        Cookie: 'odbn=1; WSS_FullScreenMode=false; rtFa=Fo9oO7...A==; FedAuth=77u...',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
        referer: '<botsite>/api/messages',
        dnt: '1',
        'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36',
        'x-requestdigest': '0x095398543A736B2AA0E6E5A8102640AF2944EB8352B192F6FFB3948047013C0E0B60767014D4775C358FED7B14075BDBAADC5A96F59875D8FC56E455BF1FAE67,01 Sep 2016 21:19:32 -0000',
        accept: 'application/json;odata=nometadata' 
    } 
};
```

Then I make a request to get the List from my sharepoint site and get an error:

```
ID4183: The Security Token failed Audience restriction validation.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [MicrosoftDX/botauth](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth), an authentication middleware for [Bot Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/) Node SDK, aka [botbuilder](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder).

You can find usage instructions in the main [README](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/blob/master/README.md) and more specifically, an [Active Directory code example here.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/tree/master/examples/aadv2)